# Install chrom on Asic

Tags: asicboost

I want to use antminer-s9 to mining from cryptotab site
This site is much more than any pool give bitcoin

Bot it doesn't have any pool . And just must use Chrome to mine
Any one know how can I install chorom on Asic or a way to connect my antminer to this site?

Comment: Cryptotab must surely be a scam, or at least something different than you think.  There is no way that a browser running on an ordinary computer can mine even a penny's worth of Bitcoin.

Comment: One possibility is that Cryptotab mines currencies other than Bitcoin, that use some hash algorithm other than SHA256D that can be done efficiently on a CPU.  But your AntMiner inherently can only do SHA256D, so it is not possible to use it to mine currencies that use other algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to run chrome on an ASIC. But if you did, whatever it mines in a tab would not make use of the ASIC hardware.

Firstly, an ASIC is not a general purpose computer, it cannot just run whatever software you want on it. It does have a small general purpose computer for managing the ASIC hardware, but that is a low powered computer. This low powered computer has a CPU which you could compile a version of Chrome for and copy the binaries to it. Then you could start an X server to get a GUI over the network and view it on another computer.

However, this would not be useful to you at all. Chrome would not be able to use the ASIC hardware. It can only use the general purpose CPU, which, in this case, is super low powered. It would not mine any more coins than a regular computer, in fact, it will most definitely mine much much less, if any at all.